# Store selected rows id

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a datatable loaded from a query from my database. (+/- 10000 records)
The idea is that the user should be able to select multiple records to be later processed

First i thought to add a column with checkbox for the selection then when user is done with all his selection the application keep track of all selected rows then progress to the next step with "Next Button" some where on the page, but after 12 hours of trying i couldn't do it.

Then i thought to make it simpler by adding a button in each row so that every time the user clicks on this button the application save the selected id in a session variable.

```
<div class="panel-body">

<table id="userTable" class="table display compact order-column">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Zipcode</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>  
</table>
```

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatable")
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {

        var ids;
        var mytable = $('#userTable').DataTable({


            "sDom": 'ltipr',
            "bServerSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "beforeSend": AjaxBegin,
                "type": "POST",
                "url": '/LocationModifier/UserHistory',
                "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'data': function (data) { return data = JSON.stringify(data); },
                'complete': AjaxComplete
            },


            "bProcessing": false,
            "orderMulti": false,
            "scrollX": true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "searchDelay": 7000,
            "fixedHeader": {
                "header": true,
                "footer": true
            },

            "columnDefs": [
                { "defaultContent": "-", "targets": "_all" },
                { "className": "text-center custom-middle-align", "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ] },
            ],

            "colReorder": true,

            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],



            "columns": [
                 {
                     "title": "Select",
                     "data": "ID",
                     "searchable": false,
                     "sortable": false,
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {

                         return '<a href="@Url.Action("AddToCache", "LocationModifier")?id=' + data + '&source=0" class="editUser"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-sm btn-info"></span></a>';
                     }
                 },

                { "data": "Name", "orderable": false },
                { "data": "City", "orderable": true },
                { "data": "Phone", "orderable": true },
                { "data": "Zipcode", "orderable": false },

            ],
            "order": []

        });

    });


</script>
```

}

```
public ActionResult AddToCache(int id)
    {
        GetRecordAndAddeToCache(id);
        // what should i return here, the page should not be refreshed????
    }
```

Comment: The checkboxes approach is not so bad. When you generate the rows, they have id's, when a checkbox is clicked add it to a JavaScript array of ids. Make action that accepts List<int> ids and that shall grab your ids on submit...

Comment: @st_stefanov that was my aim before, but i couldn't mange to do it.
after a couple of hours trying my colleague told me that i must use Datatable Edit which is not for free, so i dropped the idea. however i would appreciate it if you have an example somewhere, i have little experience with front end scripting

Comment: I am working on making an example for you. I will show an MVC approach as well. Give me some time.

Comment: I think this one is pretty close to what you need: http://www.gunaatita.com/Blog/Send-multiple-checkbox-values-from-view-to-controller-in-MVC/1047   or this: http://www.tutorialspanel.com/pass-multiple-checkbox-values-from-view-to-controller-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: @st_stefanov thank you for your help.
The problem with these example is that i will lose the benifits of jquery datatable so i will have to implement my slef paging, filtering sorting ... etc

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg yes and i wrote the results under your answer. thanks

Comment: @Maro : Please, note, I have removed spread operator from my code to make it as much browser agnostic as possible. Does it work for you now?

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg still strageling with some 'invalid character' errors that prevent the page from loading example: in the line "return `<input type="checkbox" ${rowsSelected.has(data.id) ? 'checked' : ''}></input>`;

Comment: @Maro : It looks like either Edge or Safari issue (no support for certain ES6 features). Do `return '<input type="checkbox" '+rowsSelected.has(data.id) ? 'checked' : ''+'></input>';`. And simply do `console.log(selectedRows)` to output the result of selection.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg i'm using IE , 
I tried to use 'data: null, render: function (data) {
                            var checked = $(selectedRows.has(data.ID)) ? 'checked' : '';
                            var code = '<input class="markSelected" type="checkbox" ' + checked + '></input>"';
                            return code;
                        } so i didn't get error, but first all my checkboxes are checked and the event on click is never fired

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg the following works better but i still can't get the check event to fire : var checked = selectedRows.has(data.ID) ? 'checked' : '';
                            var code = '<input class="markSelected" type="checkbox" ' + checked + '></input>"';
                            return code;

Comment: @Maro : try shorter version `.click()` it may work

Comment: @Maro : and make sure your code is wrapped with `$(document).ready()` callback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193764/discussion-between-maro-and-u25lywt5iejhc3rhcmqg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem to implement your initial approach:

- use some global set that will store selected row id's, like `var rowsSelected = new Set()`;
- add/delete id of the row being checked to that global variable upon clicking selection checkbox:

```
$('.markSelected').on('click', function () {
    const selectedRowId = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().id;
    $(this).prop('checked') ? rowsSelected.add(selectedRow) : rowsSelected.delete(selectedRow);
});
```

- upon table re-rendering append checkboxes to the first column and set those checked if rendered row id is present within `rowsSelected`:

```
render: function (data) {
    return `<input type="checkbox" ${rowsSelected.has(data.id) ? 'checked' : ''}></input>`;
}
```

The complete **demo**, implementing that concept:

```js
//table source
const srcData = [
  {id: 1, item: 'apple', cat: 'fruit'},
  {id: 2, item: 'pear', cat: 'fruit'},
  {id: 3, item: 'carrot', cat: 'vegie'},
  {id: 4, item: 'tomato', cat: 'vegie'},
  {id: 5, item: 'cucumber', cat: 'vegie'}
];

//global variable that stores selected item id's
const selectedRows = new Set();

//datatables initialization
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {data: null, render: function(data){
      return `<input class="markSelected" type="checkbox" ${selectedRows.has(data.id) ? 'checked' : ''}></input>`;
    }},
    {data: 'item', title: 'item'},
    {data: 'cat', title: 'cat'}
  ]
});

//selection checkboxes click handler
$('#mytable').click('.markSelected', function(){
  const selectedRowId = dataTable.row($(event.target).closest('tr')).data().id;
  $(event.target).prop('checked') ? selectedRows.add(selectedRowId) : selectedRows.delete(selectedRowId);
});

//proceed to the next step with selected row id's
$('#nextStep').on('click', function(){
  console.log([...selectedRows]);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
  <button id="nextStep">Next Step</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although i see it run, i have 3 problems
1- when i click on any other page number i lose all selected boxes 2- the line 'dataTable.rows().every' gives error 'datatable undefined' 3- the '()=> ' also gives error undefined.  regarding the data, i'm loading my data using server side option maybe this is the reason i'm losing selected checkboxes when i change the page.

Comment: Adjusted my answer to work with `serverSide` option set avoiding arrow notation of the functions. Just in case, `dataTable` (not `datatable`) is the variable, I assign my DataTables object to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use datatable's Row selection feature to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#userTable').DataTable();

    $('#userTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );

    $('#submitButtonId').click( function () {
        alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
        // You can use  table.rows('.selected').data()  to get all the selected Data
    } );
} );
```

[Reference](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html)

Comment: I did try this also a couple of days ago but somehow when i change the page the selections are lost, although in the sample online is not the case, also i didn't know how to capture the id's after that.