# Get array of multiple selected row id in DataTables

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, datatables

I try to select multiple rows by checkboxes in datatables jquery plugin in order to pass data to another form.

I was doing something but my code just returns selected row in the current datatable active page.

This is my form which is filled with data coming from jquery:

```
   <div class="widget-footer">

      <button id="BtnClick" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">
          صدور
      </button>
      @using (@Html.BeginForm("LineRegimeSave", "DietTherapy", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "hiddenForm" }))
      {
          <input type="hidden" name="BreakFast" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="Snake1" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="Lunch" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="Snake2" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="Snake3" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="Dinner" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="Snake4" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="AdviseText" value="@TempData["Advise"].ToString()" />
          <input type="hidden" name="docFooterId" value="@TempData["footerId"].ToString()" />
      }
  </div>
```

And this is my query :

```
        var datasets = {};
        $("#BtnClick").click(function () {

           $.each(
                $("input[type=checkbox]"),
                function() {
                    var catName = $(this).attr('name');
                    datasets[catName] = {
                        label: catName,
                        data: []
                    };
                });

           $.each(
                $("input[type=checkbox]:checked"),
                function () {
                    var catName = $(this).attr('name');
                    datasets[catName].data.push($(this).val());
                });
            var data ={};
            $.each(
                datasets,
                function (item, dt) {
                    var name = item;
                    var value = dt['data'].join(",");
                    data[name] = value;
                }
            );

            $("#hiddenForm").autofill(data);
            $("#hiddenForm").submit();
```

And you can see my table :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-up pull-right"></i>
                وعده صبحانه
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0;">
        <div class="panel-body no-padding">
                <table id="dt_basic" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable_col_reorder_info" style="width: 100%;" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th data-hide="phone" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable_col_reorder" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 31px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column descending">ردیف</th>
                            <th data-class="expand" class="expand sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable_col_reorder" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 300px;" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending">رژیم</th>
                            <th class="sorting" aria-controls="datatable_col_reorder" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Phone: activate to sort column ascending">کالری</th>
                            <th aria-controls="datatable_col_reorder" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="Phone: activate to sort column ascending">انتخاب</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{
                            //string[] cal = new[] {breakfast, snake1, lunch, snake2, snake3, dinner, snake4};

                            if (Model.Any())
                            {
                                int index = 1;
                                var breakFast = Model.Where(a => a.Mealses.Any(b => b.MealsName == "BreakFast") && a.Calories.ToString() == @ViewBag.cal[0].ToString()).ToList();
                                foreach (var itDiet in breakFast)
                                {
                                    var rowCls = "odd";
                                    rowCls = @index / 2 == 0 ? "odd" : "even";
                                    <tr role="row" class="@rowCls">
                                        <td>@index</td>
                                        <td>@itDiet.Diet</td>
                                        <td>@itDiet.Calories</td>
                                        <td class="smart-form">
                                            <label class="checkbox">
                                                <input name="BreakFast" checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="@itDiet.Id">
                                                <i></i>
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    index++;
                                }
                                index = 1;

                            }

                        }


                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I check my post method in Visual Studio I can see that I just receive the active page selected row with checkbox. Can you help me to improve my jquery code ?

**UPDATE**

If you want know where is datatables source  :
[DataTables](https://datatables.net)
And you may need to add this script to page

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugin/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugin/datatables/dataTables.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugin/datatables/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugin/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugin/datatable-responsive/datatables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.formautofill.js"></script>
```

Comment: First of all, you have alot of errors in your code that you posted so please fix those so that we can see the problem.

Comment: @MelissaSkywalkz thanks for response , Please check  datatables site for more detail ...

Comment: I still get some errors like: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: My code contain razor syntax my be it cause problem !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store selected rows id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240259/store-selected-rows-id)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://live.datatables.net/baquqore/443/edit) is Live example for jquery datatable with multi-select checkbox

and for getting selected Ids use this code

```
table.rows({ selected: true }).data().toArray().map(function (item) { return item.id; })
```

and here is code of the live example in case it no longer works

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></th>
          <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td/>
          <td>1</td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                      <td/>

            <td>2</td>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
      </table>
      
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
          
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            
                table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                    columnDefs: [ {
                targets: 0,
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '',
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                    },
                                 {
                                 targets:1,
                                 visible: false}],
                    select: {
                        style:    'multi',
                        selector: 'td:first-child'
                    },
                    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
                });
                
                $('#example').on('click', '#select_all', function () {
                    if ($('#select_all:checked').val() === 'on')
                        table.rows().select();
                    else
                        table.rows().deselect();
                });     
              
              $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function () {
                console.log(table.cell(this).render());
                console.log(table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data());
              });
              
           
            });
```